# Android не создается каталог

Tags: android, файлы

Всем привет!
Почему-то не создается каталог, ни во внутренней памяти телефона, ни на SD-карте

в манифесте разрешение есть

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

вот код создания в MainActivity

```
String sdState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); //Получаем состояние SD карты (подключена она или нет) - возвращается true и false соответственно
        if (sdState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {        // если true
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "диск есть");

                file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + DirectoryName;
                //File file = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory(),DirectoryName );

                File folder = new File(file);
                folder.mkdirs();

                if (!folder.exists()){
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Каталог не создан");
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "диска нет");
            }
```

Каталог не создается, пробовал и на эмуляторе и на реальном телефоне. Прошу помочь разобраться в чем проблема. Спасибо!

Comment: Тестируете на Android 6.0+ ? Про runtime permission знает https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно начиная с 6.0, разрешение необходимо запрашивать отдельно у пользователя. Совсем забыл про это. pavlofff спасибо за подсказку.

На всякий случай, кому пригодится, нашел библиотеку которая существенно упрощает работу с разрешениями https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: но я ничего не подсказывал про permission, это комментарий @temq

Answer (score 0):

Кусок моего кода - правда у меня копируется файл, но кусок непосредственно проверки наличия директории для файла и создании ее перед копированием (оба параметра - пути с именами файлов, поэтому вызывается getParentFile)

```
public static void copyFile(File fileFrom, File fileTo) throws IOException {
    // проверка наличия директории для копирования
    if (!fileTo.getParentFile().exists())
        fileTo.getParentFile().mkdirs();

   ...

}
```

Еще один момент по вашему коду - проверка карты памяти некорректна, она смотрит не только карту но и внутреннюю память устройства размеченную как внешняя. Недавно перекапывал весь интернет - вроде нашел неплохой код, слегка для себя поправил:

```
public static boolean externalSdIsMounted(){
    String s = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    if(s == null)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```